# "Already put on hold" message is too generic on iOS

Tags: bug, ios-app, on-hold

The iOS app for Stack Exchange gives a generic message when you try to flag a question to be on hold, unlike its behavior on the website:

[image: Website error message]

Instead, the app simply gives you a generic message telling you nothing about it already being on hold.

Comment: So what is the actual message you get?